# polling with setTimeout in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why with this code, does it only console.log 'do stuff' twice?

```
class Something extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.doStuff();
    }

    doStuff() {
        console.log('do stuff')
        setTimeout(this.doStuff, 3000);
    }

    render() {
        return null
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `this` might be getting lost. Maybe try `setTimeout(this.doStuff.bind(this), 3000);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the first timeout, `this` will be the `window` object, and you have no `doStuff` method on the `window` object, so it will not run again.

You could e.g. make the `doStuff` function into an arrow function, which will have the `this` value of the enclosing lexical context instead.

```js
class Something extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.doStuff();
    }

    doStuff = () => {
        console.log('do stuff');
        setTimeout(this.doStuff, 1000);
    }

    render() {
        return null;
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Something />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```